# libGDX: how to make a world to move

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm a newbie in libgdx and  working on a simple 2d game and I want that my box2d world(or background) move with the input touch(move upward when I press the button) but I don't know how to move the world and place my player on the center. I want to know:

1. How to move my world with the input control.
2. Place my player in the center.

and also it looks like that my player is moving whenever I play that game, not the world.
if you can just provide an example with your answer.

so, Here is my code

```
 public void show() {
        world = new World(new Vector2(0, 25), true);
        renderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
      /*  cam.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2, 0);
        cam.update();*/


        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture("img/imgs.png");
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.setSize(10, 10);
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
        sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
        //sprite.setBounds(200, 200, 64, 64);
        //sprite.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2 -sprite.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2-sprite.getHeight()/2);


       /* //Body definition
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(0, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2 - 250);

        box = world.createBody(bodyDef);

        //Polygon Shape
        PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
        shape.setAsBox(10, 20);


        //fixture definition
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixtureDef.shape = shape;
        fixtureDef.density = 5f;
        fixtureDef.friction = .5f;

        box.createFixture(fixtureDef);

        box.setUserData(sprite);

        shape.dispose();

*/    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        world.step(1 / 60f, 6, 2);
        cam.translate(0, 12);
        cam.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
            spriteY += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * spriteSpeed;
        if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
            spriteY += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() * sprite1Speed;



        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(sprite, spriteX, spriteY);
        batch.end();

        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.rect(0, 200, 50, 50);
        shapeRenderer.translate(1, 0, 0);
        shapeRenderer.end();


    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        cam.viewportWidth = width;
        cam.viewportHeight = height;
        cam.update();


    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        //world.dispose();
        shapeRenderer.dispose();
        batch.dispose();


    }

}
```

Sorry, for the mess(I'm a novice) in code and I want that my world moves upwards with input controls and my sprite just placed in the center.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you want to create a platformer or kinda.

I'll let you know that the best way to build your logic on when creating a (2d) platformer game is your character should always keep it's position the same and the background and other solid objects should *move* towards the player (based on input controls or automatic) so giving the look like your player is naturally moving and the background & objects appear in his way.

My answer is pretty general as your question is pretty general. If you need code you must provide us code so we know where you're stuck. Good luck :)

Comment: Also placing the player in center is an abstract question as it depends on the way you paint the objects/ textures. A simple google or youtube search won't hurt as you can easily find lots of useful beginner tutorials.

Comment: Why would you do it that way? You'd have to move all of the objects in the world instead of one object. And there could be no static physics bodies except the player itself. The only situation I can think of where this might make sense is in an infinite, progressive stage, where only a sliver of the world exists at a time and you don't want to start losing precision when the player gets far from the origin.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes that's about infinite scrollers but not only. The objects u talking about could only be 2-3 objects that always respawn in the visual area giving sensation that it is a new obstacle there but it's just the one which u passed few seconds earlier. Having the character not changing his relative position at all excludes really many conditions and facts that you should check in order to make the background scroll/repeat.

Comment: Now I'm providing the code and yes I'm trying to make an infinite platformer game

Comment: Okay so u want the world to move upwards and the player center aligned. What do you get so far?

Comment: I created the world and a sprite image(kind of my player) which is moving upward with input control but after it goes upward it was out of my world and my camera doesn't follow my player that's why now I wanted to move my world. Actually, I do not have any idea about how should I move my world and make my camera to focus on my player

Comment: If u want the camera to follow something (a character) you got to set the `cam.position.x` and `cam.position.y` according to the character's position before calling `cam.update()`. Have a look here for more details: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/83175/libgdx-how-to-make-camera-follow-the-player

Comment: I tried everything but nothing worked for me that's why I tried to move the world this time or may be I am missing something.

Comment: @Shubham Garg I highly recommend [this libGDX tutorial](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/page/LibGDX-Tutorial-series.aspx), it is made for beginners willing to create games with it and it covers really big part of the things you need **(including animations, motion control, actions and many more)**. Actually following & finishing a _good tutorial_ is the best to do before asking _all_ the questions ;) good luck